# How would I model this relation in my POCO's in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My question is about the below shown schema. I have a `Tenant` which has `InboundSources` which, in turn, have `InboundSourceActions`. I **cannot** change the database schema whatsoever since it belongs to a third-party product that relies on this exact schema.

[image: Schema]

I have the following classes (the `Tenant` is irrelevant but included to show how I have my navigation properties set up / ensure it works as I want to):

```
[Table("tenants")]
public class Tenant
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("tenant")]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ...blah blah

    // Navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<InboundSource> InboundSources { get; set; }
}

[Table("inbound_source")]
public class InboundSource
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties back to Tenant
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // ...blah blah

    // Navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<InboundSourceAction> InboundSourceActions { get; set; }
}

[Table("inbound_source_actions")]
public class InboundSourceAction
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation property back to InboundSource
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public virtual InboundSource InboundSource { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    // ...blah blah
}
```

I'm having trouble implementing the Navigation Properties from/to `InboundSource` and `InboundSourceActions`. The relation is shown in red in the above schema but not actually in the database as Foreign Keys or anything. I am looking for how to model the red relation in the `InboundSource` and `InboundSourceAction` classes. I've been trying adding `ForeignKey` attributes but cannot get it to work:

```
[Table("inbound_source")]
public class InboundSource
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Blah blah

    [ForeignKey("Extension")]
    public virtual ICollection<InboundSourceAction> InboundSourceActions { get; set; }
}

[Table("inbound_source_actions")]
public class InboundSourceAction
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    [ForeignKey("InboundSource")]
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public virtual InboundSource InboundSource { get; set; }

    // Blah blah
}
```

But this results in an exception: `'InboundSourceAction_InboundSource_Target_InboundSourceAction_InboundSource_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'Extension' on entity 'InboundSourceAction' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'InboundSource' in the referential constraint 'InboundSourceAction_InboundSource'.
'`.

So my question: does EF support such a scenario at all, and if it does, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF6, an Entity has a single Key, and any Foreign Keys must refer to the Entity Key.  But EF doesn't care *which* key you declare as the Entity Key.  If inbound_source as two keys, (ID) and (Extension), you can declare either one as the Entity Key.

Comment: Yeah, I moved the `[Key]` attribute to the `Extension` property and this happens to work with this specific object (even though `id` is the ACTUAL key...). However, I do have other objects where the FK doesn't refer to a key. But that'll be a problem for another day.

Thanks!

Comment: A FK always refers to a Key.  That's a rule.  But you don't even need a Key in the database to declare an Entity Key.  Of course you'll get some weird behavior if you try to update an Entity based on a declared Entity Key that isn't actually unique and indexed in the database.